# How to add some option to a select box above all mapping in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to add an  **All** Option to my existing select box.
Select box is creating with some API data. With the API data set I want to add an **ALL** option above.

This is my code.

```
const useChemicals = () => {
const [data, setData]: any = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
const getChemicalsData = async () => {
  try {
    const results = await searchApi.requestChemicalsList();
   
    if (results.data) {         
      let groupCount = 0;
      const chemList: any = [];     
          
      results.data.data.chemicals.map((chemical: any, index: number) => {   
        if (chemical.key === '') {
          chemList.push({
            label: chemical.value,
            options: [],
          });
        }
      });
       
      results.data.data.chemicals.map((chemical: any, index: number) => {
        
        if (chemical.key === '') {
          if (index > 1) {
            groupCount += 1;
          }
        } else {
          chemList[groupCount].options.push({
            label: chemical.value,
            value: chemical.key,
          });
        }
      });
      
      setData([...chemList]);
    }
  } catch (e) {}
};
getChemicalsData();
}, []);
return data && data;
};
export default useChemicals;
```

[image]

How can I add this. Please help me, I am new to React.

Comment: Seems like you are rendering multiple selectors? Maybe `const chemList: any[] = [{label: 'all', value: 'all'}]` is what you need. Hard to say without seeing how the data is used. Btw, don't use `.map` if you are not actually doing anything with the return value. Either use `.forEach` or actually returns something from the callback and do `chemList = chemList.concat(results.data.data.chemicals.map(...))` instead.

Comment: @FelixKling thank you for your response, I am performing a search using this data render in the select box. I Updated the code in question